# "Enhance your looks"

Tags: word-choice

Does "enhance your looks" sound natural?

For context: "Changes are important for us. We need them. My friend is going to have a plastic surgery to enhance her looks. She wants to be as beautiful on the outside as she is on the inside."

Comment: Yes. That is a completely fine usage

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/116757/discussion-on-question-by-antonia-a-enhance-your-looks).